# Excel use COUNTIF with dynamic input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a cell value (in `F8`) to enter keywords to search for in column `B` of another sheet (`Sep Miss` which is in the same workbook). I want to return a total count where the input may be a whole or partial match. The `$B` is `BC` - I am drag copying across rows.

What I've tried:

```
=CountIf('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, F8)  
=CountIf('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, "*F8*")  
=CountIF('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, Summary!F8)  
=CountIF('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, "Summary!F8")  
=CountIF('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, "*Summary!F8*")
```

Comment: Thanks Robin for the formatting help. Still a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  Something like:

```
=CountIF('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, "*"&Summary!F8&"*")
```

Comment: i think Summary!F8 should not be in quotes. `=CountIF('Sep Miss'!$B:$B, "*" & Summary!F8 & "*") `

Comment: @nightcrawler23  Good Catch

Comment: Awesome! this works. Thank you Gary and Nightcrawler.